# Including a library of Javascript to be used within a script task

Tags: javascript, camunda

I'm adding a couple of script tasks to a BPMN model and I wonder if there's anyway I can have some Javascript shared among them? Perhaps including the library somewhere in the model (embedded) and have them available in all of the script tasks within that model?

Comment: Mehran, were you able to figure this out? We're running into a similar need.

Comment: @MustafaAlammar Unfortunately, no. I have not.

Comment: Probably this can help: https://forum.camunda.org/t/loading-javascript-files-from-deployment-using-load/3419/13?